# Laravel: WhereBetween Date with request date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

i want to get data between two times with dates
like this code working

```
$jodies = DisawarJodi::whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subDay()->format('Y-m-d') . " 08:00:00", now()->format('Y-m-d') . " 2:50:00"])->get();
```

but when i use request its not working

```
$date = Carbon::parse($request->date);
$jodies = DisawarJodi::whereBetween('created_at', [$date->subDay()->format('Y-m-d') . " 08:00:00", $date->format('Y-m-d') . " 2:50:00"])->get();
```

whats wrong with this code

Comment: can you `dd($request->date)`?

Comment: yeah i am getting string `"2020-04-04"` like this

Answer (score 0):

`Carbon::parse` can be a little problematic as it does it's best interpretation of the format but can easily get it wrong.

Try `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->date);`

This way you are explicit about which character represents what in the date.

Comment: i am getting error 
InvalidArgumentException
The format separator does not match
 The format separator does not match
 The format separator does not match
 The format separator does not match
 The format separator does not match
 Data missing

Comment: working code is `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->date)` but still not getting data

Comment: Try `dd($date)` just to check that it is a Carbon object with the correct value. This won't fix the issue but it will let us know more about what we are working with!